# Mysql I keep getting total jobs in return

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

I have sql query where i like to get total records.

I have one employer and 600 jobs by this employer.

I need to get all the employers but for some reason my query is returning total jobs which employer posted.

Please let me know what i'm going wrong in this query.

```
SELECT count(c.id) as total 
FROM employer as c INNER JOIN  job as j ON j.employerIDFK = c.id 
WHERE c.isActive=1 AND c.status=1 
AND j.isActive=1 
AND j.beenActive=1 
AND j.status=1 
AND DATE_ADD( j.createdAt, INTERVAL 30 DAY ) > NOW()
```

Comment: A few things jump out at me about this query.  1)  Use proper joins.  Implicit joins cause tons of problems (I suspect it's involved in this actually).  2)  Precalculate NOW() - 30 days and then use that value to compare with j.createdAt.  That way, you can avoid a full table scan (if j.createdAt is indexed).

Comment: I need to get full list of jobs which are still less then 30 days. I dont know what you mean by Precalculate NOW()?

Comment: Since the value of NOW() is constantly changing, MySQL must compare recalculate it for each and every row.  This means that even without the DATE_ADD, a full table scan would be required.  Basically, you have this:  `a + b < c`.  However, a can be indexed, meaning if you can get a comparison involving just a and not a function of a, you can exploit this index.  In other words, you want to change it into `a < c - b`.  However, c is constantly changing, so you still must do a complete table scan (indexes can only work with constants).

Comment: So, what is the short version of what I'm saying?  Calculate now() - 30 days in PHP.  Basically j.createdAt < $date with `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now -30 days));`

Comment: if I have 6000 jobs which will be some still within 30 and some will be more then 30 i will be pulling all the data. then be compare in php this would make it slow to load. at the moment i'm only getting jobs which are less then 30 days and approved and active.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you pull all the data from SQL and then filter it in PHP.  I'm suggesting that you precalculate the WHERE clause.

Comment: so in select i can do NOW() as current time and then compare it in where clause.

Comment: @Corbin: the value of `NOW()` never changes during the query (or a trigger, or a stored procedure). It's `SYSDATE()` which changes. Predicates involving `NOW()` may be sargable (the one in the original query is not of course, but not because of `NOW()`).

Comment: You need to put your GROUP clause back in if you're expecting to get the count for each employer.

Comment: @Quassnoi  I've always assumed that now is recalculated. Oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS total 
FROM    employer c
JOIN    job j
ON      j.employerIDFK = c.id
WHERE   c.isActive = 1
        AND c.status = 1
        AND j.isActive = 1 
        AND j.beenActive = 1 
        AND j.status = 1 
        AND j.createdAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Create the following indexes:

```
employer (isActive, status)
job (employerFKID)
job (isActive, beenActive, status, createdAt, employerFKID)
```

for the query to work faster.

If for some obscure reasons you are reluctant to use `DISTINCT`, you may use this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(c.id) AS total
FROM    employer c
WHERE   c.isActive = 1
        AND c.status = 1
        AND c.id IN
        (
        SELECT  employerIDFK
        FROM    job j
        WHERE   j.isActive = 1
                AND j.beenActive = 1
                AND j.status = 1
                AND j.createdAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        )
```

, however, this may be less efficient, as `MySQL` cannot make `job` leading in this kind of query.

Comment: This does work. I'm only getting 1 record now which is correct. but can this be done without DISTINCT

Comment: @Lalajee: what do you have against `DISTINCT`?

Comment: in past been told to avoid this.

Comment: @Lalajee: I hereby absolve you from this limitation. `DISTINCT` is fine to use (at least in this query).

Comment: thank you. you have no idea what you have done for me. i was trying to fix this for week now i was not able to see why my query was return wrong answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Lalajee: is this answer helped you, please upvote it and make accepted.

Comment: @Quassnoi You can use your original query by adding a group by c.id which would remove the dup, which is same as distinct.

Comment: @Quassnoi but since you are using JOIN format, instead of FROM table1, table2, you should also levage the fact that if you add in more condition in your join, you are reducing the set of data the two table is doing a cartesian join on. Because SQL evaluate the FROM/JOIN clause before it moves onto the WHERE clause. In the From/Join clause if you are able to filter more, you will have less rows to map to each other. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/sql_1016.htm look for Reviewing the Execution Plan

Comment: i did use from but then i use join. i have remove join and added from t1, t2

Comment: @Churk: `SQL` does not "evaluate `FROM` before `JOIN`", it's not how the optimizer works. It optimizes the query as a whole. In partucular, implicit and explicit inner joins are optimized to the same plan. Also, why are you linking `Oracle` documentation to a question tagged `mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be returning a count for all jobs for all employers, but there are some criteria that they must match to show up. An implicit join, as you are using, is an INNER JOIN. This requires all criteria to match in order for the rows to be included. This means it only returns jobs that are "isActive", "beenActive", "status=1", and createdAt is less than 30 days in the past, where employeres are "isActive" and "status=1". Check your data to see if this is what you want.

```
SELECT c.id AS employerID, count(*) as total 
FROM employer as c, job as j 
WHERE c.isActive=1 AND c.status=1 
AND j.employerIDFK = c.id 
AND j.isActive=1 
AND j.beenActive=1 
AND j.status=1 
AND DATE_ADD( j.createdAt, INTERVAL 30 DAY ) > NOW()
GROUP BY c.id
```

As far as what others are trying to say regarding the filter on the createdAt, MySQL will first evaluate NOW() (just once). It then adds 30 days to each createdAt date to see if it's greater than NOW(). MySQL will sometimes automatically optimize this, and it depends on your version and some other factors, but in general, performing a function against the createdAt date for each row to compare it to a constant expression is bad because MySQL can't utilize an index on the createdAt column.

So, you should convert:

```
AND DATE_ADD( j.createdAt, INTERVAL 30 DAY ) > NOW()
```

To this:

```
AND j.createdAt > DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY )
```

This leaves j.createdAt column as a plain column, so MySQL can now utilize any index against the column to find dates that are less than 30 days in the past.

It's the equivalent of standing in a room with 100 people and asking them to add 30 days to their birthday, then asking who's calculated date is greater than today. You just made 100 people do work. Instead, precalculate the criteria by subtracting 30 days from today's date and simply ask if anyone's birthday is greater than that date. You only had to do one calculation, and it saved those 100 people from having to do the hard work.

Comment: Thank you for fix for my date value. Sorry my problem is that I need to return numbers on employers which have posted job and they jobs are less then 30 days. But I keep getting 604 records where I should only get 1 record as I only have 1 employer in my employer table.

Comment: i do have 604 jobs which are posted by this employer.

Comment: @Lalajee, I updated my answer to provide an analogy. Where'd your GROUP clause go?

Comment: Even with Group i'm still getting 604 records

Comment: I try almost every thing but still i get same results. I think my query is missing something.

Comment: So, do you have 604 active employers with active jobs? By 604 records. do you mean 604 counts, or the total of all counts is 604?

Comment: I have 1 active employer with 604 jobs

Comment: @Lalajee, Well, there you go. Check your data.

Comment: Because i have 1 employer my query should only return 1 employer but for some reason its returning the total record of jobs

Comment: You just said that you have one employer with 604 jobs, and you're getting one row, with a count of 604. That seems correct. I modified the query in my answer to include the employer ID in the SELECT clause. Take a look. :) It's funny. Computers do exactly what we ask them to do. :)

Comment: i need to get total employers not total jobs. I'm getting total record of 604 but I only have 1 record. my query is showing 604 records. but i dont have 604 employers in database.

Comment: When I run this SELECT count(*) as total FROM employer as c. i get 1 record in return.

Comment: but when i run this SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM employer as c, job as j 
WHERE c.isActive=1 AND c.status=1 
AND j.employerIDFK = c.id 
AND j.isActive=1 
AND j.beenActive=1 
AND j.status=1 
AND j.createdAt > DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY )
GROUP BY c.id. i get 604 records

Comment: @Lalajee, that's just one record. That records says 604, but it's just one record. Take a look above. I've added the employer ID. I'm going to go away now because I think you need to take a moment to digest what's going on. Good luck. Don't forget to upvote my answer if you found it helpful. Thanks.

Comment: sorry i think you not understand what i'm trying to get out of this query.

Comment: I have two tables employer and job. I like to get number total number of employer. I only have 1 employer in my database.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect "SELECT count(*) as total" is your problem. You are asking SQL to count everything that is returned. Watch out for what you are "SELECT"-ing since that's the only thing which will be returned to you.

You didn't quite explain what you're trying to achieve here. "I need to get all the employers" is vague and hard to understand. What data are you trying to get about the employers? Their ID? Their total jobs?

Comment: this is just the total records for my Pagination. I need to ask system to return total numbers of employers which have post jobs on site.